# Catch exception thrown in foreach condition

Tags: c#, exception, foreach, try-catch

I have a `foreach` loop that breaks during the loop in the condition of the foreach itself. Is there a way to `try catch` the item that throws the exception and then continue the loop?

This will run a few times until the exception hits and then end.

```
try {
  foreach(b in bees) { //exception is in this line
     string += b;
  }
} catch {
   //error
}
```

This will not run at all because the exception is in the condition of the foreach

```
foreach(b in bees) { //exception is in this line
   try {
      string += b;
   } catch {
     //error
   }
}
```

I know some of you are going to ask how this is happening so here is this:
Exception `PrincipalOperationException` is being thrown because a `Principal` (b in my example) cannot be found in `GroupPrincipal` (bees).

**Edit:** I added the code below. I also figured out that one group member was pointing to a domain that no longer exists. I easily fixed this by deleting the member but my question still stands. How do you handle exceptions that are thrown inside the condition of a foreach?

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.domain);
GroupPrincipal gp1 = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "gp1");
GroupPrincipal gp2 = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "gp2");

var principals = gp1.Members.Union(gp2.Members);

foreach(Principal principal in principals) { //error is here
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't in a "condition". It's in the process of enumerating the `bees` object. For debugging purposes, try to "manually" enumerate `bees`. It's some sort of `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable`. Manually do `.MoveFirst()` and see if you get the exception right away.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize C#'s didn't have a resume on next... I just found all these forums of guys looking for the equivalent. I suppose its just another good thing about a being a VB.net developer. My apologies mates

Comment: @mellamokb, Actually I don't use it too much myself. I used to work with a rather interesting C++ programmer who was forced to write in Vb.net, he would litter the damn code with On error resume next. Why would I just make something up here?

Comment: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1275 Here is someone using it.

Comment: Can you provide your actual code, i.e. at least the actual classes being involved (is it this [`GroupPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal.aspx) you mean? Because I cannot see that it is even enumerable.). Maybe we can find a more "domain specific" solution for your problem then, which could ultimately be easier than the "generic" case.

Comment: I summon @JonSkeet the master of Linq and Enumeration to bring us his lights.

Comment: The 'allow skip of bad element' needs to be done in the enumeration logic itself (the implementation of `bees`); an exception in enumeration will most likely leave the enumerator in a state where it can no longer enumerate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost the same as the answer from @Guillaume, but "I like mine better":

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TryForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<Exception> handler)
    {
        if (sequence == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
        }

        if (handler == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("handler");
        }

        var mover = sequence.GetEnumerator();
        bool more;
        try
        {
            more = mover.MoveNext();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            handler(e);
            yield break;
        }

        while (more)
        {
            yield return mover.Current;
            try
            {
                more = mover.MoveNext();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                handler(e);
                yield break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like mine better also... However it makes more sense to throw exception than executing the `Action` if there's no enumeration. What's the reason for executing first the `MoveNext` rather than just doing it in the loop?

Comment: @Guillaume: not a big deal, but this way there is no return from the middle of the loop. It's a minor style issue, and a little bit less to have to think about.

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the Enumerator!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try to create a method like that:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> TryForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Action executeCatch)
    {
        if (list == null) { executeCatch(); }
        IEnumerator<T> enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();
        bool success = false;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                success = enumerator.MoveNext();
            }
            catch
            {
                executeCatch();
                success = false;
            }

            if (success)
            {
                T item = enumerator.Current;
                yield return item;
            }
        } while (success);
    }
```

and you can use it this way:

```
        foreach (var bee in TryForEach(bees.GetMembers(), () => { Console.WriteLine("Error!"); }))
        {
        }
```

Comment: not well programed: list.Count(); enumerates the complete list already, and the for loop is also the wrong way to enumerate an enumeration

Comment: I guess it does not work, because list.Count() already throws the error message

Comment: additionally, why should enumerator.MoveNext(); return a good value after throwing an exception?

Comment: @user287107 you are right. I improved the code to handle to handle the `Count()` issue.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The OP was talking about some `GroupPrincipal`. I just took the `GetMembers` method of that class for the sake of having an enumeration. But it could actually be anything...

Comment: now it could work, but it does not change anything compared to the first source code part in the question. if an exception occurs, the catch block gets active. the only difference is, that if an exception occures within the foreach loop, it is not caught by the exception handler in your case. adding an extra exception handling within the foreach loop would make it completely identical